# jquery parse and insert automatically nested object keys and values into correspondant div

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I have the following object example:

```
"experience": {
    "1": {
        "jobtitle": "job_title",
        "companyname": "company_name",
        "companytown": "company_town",
        "companycountry": "company_country",
        "summary": "Summary",
        "exp_from_month": "August",
        "exp_from_year": "2009",
        "exp_to_year": "2009",
        "current_position": "false"
    },
    "2": {
        "jobtitle": "job_title",
        "companyname": "company_name",
        "companytown": "company_town",
        "companycountry": "company_country",
        "summary": "Summary",
        "exp_from_month": "August",
        "exp_from_year": "2009",
        "exp_to_year": "2009",
        "current_position": "false"
    }
}
```

var key = the object key
var val = the correspondant value

I have an HTML structure like this example:

```
<div id='experience"+key+"'>
    <p>
        <strong>
            <textarea cols='30' rows='1' name='job_title"+key+"' style=''>+value+</textarea>
        </strong>&nbsp;
        <input type='checkbox' id='current_position"+key+"' checked="++value++">&nbsp;Current Position</p>
    <p>
        <textarea name='company_name"+key+"' cols='30' rows='1' style=''>"++value++"</textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <textarea name='company_town"+key+"' cols='30' rows='1' style=''>"++value++"</textarea>&nbsp;
        <textarea name='company_country"+key+"' cols='30'
        rows='1' style=''>"++value++"</textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a
        href='#' class='save_experience"+key+"' onclick='addexperience("+key+")'>Edit</a>
    </p>
    <p id='experince_dates"+key+"'>From:
        <select name='experience_from_month"+key+"' style='width:100px;'>
            <option>"++value++"</option>
        </select>&nbsp;
        <select name='experience_from_year"+key+"' style='width:100px;'>
            <option>"++value++"</option>
        </select>&nbsp;To:
        <select name=experience_to_month "+key+" ' style='width:100px;'>
            <option>August</option>
        </select>&nbsp;
        <select name='experience_to_year "+key+" ' style='width:100px; '>
            <option>2009</option>
        </select>&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>
        <textarea name='experience_summary "+key+" ' rows='5 ' cols='120 ' style=''>Summary</textarea>
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I make this possible for each `experience` inside the object?

Comment: multi line code please? that markup is unreadable. I was going to edit it, but i changed my mind, it's too much.

Comment: edited already, any ideas please ?

Comment: You mean someone else edited it for you. Please post well formatted code in the future.

Comment: yes am not i am is the one. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for(var key in experience)
    $('body').append('<div id="experience' + key + '">' + experience[key].jobtitle + '</div>');
```

Comment: thanks fot the response, i have tried this its working, but i need to insert each keys and value in the divs as the structure stated above

Comment: When you have the key and you know how to get the values, just build your content string.

Comment: how ? your code is working for single object. my object have inside, more than one, how can i loop through the number of the nested objects. with your code i am getting first nested object repeating

Comment: You have your `experience` object, which has two properties `1` and `2`. They are also objects through which my code is looping. There are no more nested objects.